# Get all accounts signed in on chrome browser from chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, google-account

I am building a chrome extension and I'm redirecting the user to a google meet page. Google uses something like `?authuser=X` at the end of URL to determine the google account to use with a video call. I want to get the `X` for the specific email I have which is signed in on google meet so that I can redirect the user to google meet with that account. Is there some way to list all the signed In accounts on the chrome browser with their number `X`?